# Trigger a search focus and if found auto next focus else show error message - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, html

Hi I have a search() function and also use autofocusnext-on-enter directive on same input feild. Validate this field which needs data query from database using the search() function. Now my challenge is how to use both search() and autofocusnext-on-enter on the same input field.

The autofocusnext-on-enter should be called only if corresponding value is found (returned by the query) else focus should remain on the field and display an error that "search data not found"

Answer (score 0):

Your directive needs a condition that is a result of an async operation. Extend the directive to accept a function it can use to register its focus method. The caller (the controller) can then call the directive method when the worker (search) completes successfully.

Here's the code

```js
angular
  .module('FocusAppDemo', [])
  .controller('MainController', mainController)
  .directive('autoFocus', autoFocus);

function mainController($timeout) {
  var controller = this;
  var _successFn, _errorFn;
  controller.setTriggerFns = function(successTrigger, errorTrigger) {
    _successFn = successTrigger;
    _errorFn = errorTrigger;
  };

  controller.search = function() {
    // replace $timeout with real async call
    $timeout(1000).then(function() {
      if (_successFn) _successFn();
    }).catch(function(error) {
      if (_errorFn) _errorFn(error)
    });
  }

  return controller;
}

function autoFocus() {
  var _attrs;

  var directiveConfig = {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      setTriggerFns: '='
    },
    link: link
  };



  function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
    _attrs = attrs;
    // can add a function for error
    scope.setTriggerFns(focusNext);
  }

  function focusNext() {
    try {
      if (_attrs.tabindex !== undefined) {
        var currentTabIndex = _attrs.tabindex;
        var nextTabIndex = parseInt(currentTabIndex) + 1;
        var nextTabQuerySelector = '[tabindex="' + nextTabIndex + '"]';
        var nextItem = document.querySelector(nextTabQuerySelector);

        if (nextItem) nextItem.focus()

      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Focus error: ' + e);
    }
  }

  return directiveConfig;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="FocusAppDemo">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-controller="MainController as demoController">
    <div>
      <input type="text" tabindex="0" ng-submit="demoController.search()" auto-focus set-trigger-fns="demoController.setTriggerFns" />
      <button ng-click="demoController.search()">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" tabindex="1" />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please @Bowofola, find my directive as below. Please make necessary changes as possible as i have failed to find a workable solution.

Comment: do you want the enter key to trigger auto focus? what triggers the search?

Comment: Enter Key triggers the search and search returns some value i.e data is found then displays it and auto focus the next input field and if data if not found i.e search returns no value then search field is cleared and set to focus.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my directive. Please make necessary changes

```
angular.module('textareafocus',[]).directive('NextFocusOnEnterKey', function() {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code === 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          try {
            if (attrs.tabindex !== undefined) {
              var currentTabeIndex = attrs.tabindex;
              var nextTabIndex = parseInt(currentTabeIndex) + 1;
              var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[tabindex]");
              for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
                var el = angular.element(elems[i]);
                var idx = parseInt(el.attr('tabindex'));
                if (idx === nextTabIndex) {
                  elems[i].focus();
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('Focus error: ' + e);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```